# Determining if Two Network Requests Occur in Parallel via TCP Port

Tags: networking, http

I have a question from an assignment asking if two HTTP network requests occur in parallel or serially.

The answer provided is that:

> they occur serially, since each network request occurs on a different TCP port.

Why does having separate TCP ports indicate that the HTTP network requests are serial?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on who initiate the request. If it is the same code, it can either be serial or in parallel, depending on how the code is written (a simpler one will be serial, a browser will do them in parallel). If there are 2 separate process doing a connect, they are in parallel (in their view, later on they can be serial from the point of view of the OS if it is not multi threaded in some way)

Comment: If one is being literal, *every* request that crosses the network in a given direction must occur serially since the network interface can only transmit or receive one packet/frame at a time. But it's unclear from the information given from who's perspective the question is being asked (network, OS, application, etc.) so it would be difficult to answer without that information.